# Cropping images in CodeIgniter for FPDF output

Tags: codeigniter, fpdf

I need to crop down some images that are pulled out from a db but when I this for example:

```
$config['source_image'] = 'imagepath';
$config['x_axis'] = '50';
$config['y_axis'] = '50';
$config['dynamic_output'] = true;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->pdf->image($this->image_lib->crop(), 150, 108, 138);
```

The image is cropped but it only displays the image and not the image in the pdf file.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give destion of image when using FPDF function. When you using 'imagelib -> crop()` it only return boolean(success/fail) about image cropped or not . Try this:

```
$config['source_image'] = 'imagepath';
$config['x_axis'] = '50';
$config['y_axis'] = '50';
$config['dynamic_output'] = true;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
if($this->image_lib->crop()) {
  //success
  $this->pdf->image($config['source_image'], 150, 108, 138);
}
else {
  //fail
  $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the image displays in the browser but the pdf document file still doesn't.