# CROP IMAGE IN FPDF is possible?

Tags: php, image, crop, fpdf

May i crop images in FPDF ? 
i have try this one [Cropping images in CodeIgniter for FPDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928933/cropping-images-in-codeigniter-for-fpdf-output) but does not work

Answer (score 2):

You can use clipping areas: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script78.php

With this extension you can define your visible area and output your image like this:

```
$pdf->ClippingRect($x, $y, $w, $h);
$pdf->Image($imageFile, $x - $imgOffsetX, $y - $imgOffsetY);
$pdf->UnsetClipping();
```

The whole image will be included in the pdf. If size matters, cropping the image file first can be the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can not crop an image in FPDF.  You must first crop the image before using it to create a PDF using FPDF.  I can recommend doing this manually, or programmatically via ImageMagick.  Then once you have your cropped jpg, gif or png, call [Image](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm).

```
$pdf->Image('croppedImage.png');
```